# How to quickly generate models in play framework 1.2?

Tags: playframework

Does play framework have anything like quickly generator of models by schema? I like symfony + doctrine infrastructure, but I can't use it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Minute-Project](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/Play)  should do what you want. How ever you still need a lot of time to make the generated code suitable. A second possibility is the [jpa-gen-module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/jpagen).

Comment: Jpagen fits for me, but it doesn't work 'Invalid command: jpagen:create-list'. I installed it (play install jpa-gen-module) and added '-play -> jpagen'. Could you explain how to correctly install that?

Comment: It's a few month ago that I do it and it works following the documentation. List `play modules` jpagen?

Answer (score 4):

The db module can do that

http://www.playframework.org/modules/db-1.1.1/home#aCreatingyourdomainmodelfromthedatabasea

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one in Play, but you can probably use the [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) tools to generate `@Entity` classes and modify them afterwards to extend `Model` or `GenericModel`.

Comment: Hmmm... Could you give me some examples?

Comment: A bit of googling got me this link: http://www.wikihow.com/Generate-Hibernate-Pojo-Classes-from-DB-Tables