# Play 2 Framework code generation tool or Yii/Cakephp frameworks?

Tags: frameworks, web, playframework, yii, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to get started with a couple of web applications. However, choosing a framework to work with can be overwhelming!

I've worked with Java in the past, and since I do C# .NET at work, I don't mind learning and extending my Java knowledge. Now, the only framework that seems to work without jsp and other applet things that I've never understood is Play 2 Framework. I downloaded this framework, put the executable file in my path, and it seems that it would work for me. However, I came across CakePHP and Yii frameworks (I'm sure there is more) and notice there is a code generation tool that gets the database and automatically generates the models for you + the CRUD and such. Geez that is a save of time.

I went and googled my question and got that this is also possible in Play Framework (bummer only found the module for 1.x framework.)

[How to quickly generate models in play framework 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033139/how-to-quickly-generate-models-in-play-framework-1-2)

http://www.playframework.org/modules/db

So, my question is...

**Is there a module that would easily let you do this work in Java Play 2.0 Framework as in the mentioned PHP frameworks?**

**If no, would it be worthy (any advantages) to stick to the Java Framework?**

**If no, what php framework or even python (but Ruby) framework you consider has the best tools like this auto completion feature?** I don't mean learning a new language, I will have to anyways. But rather to learn a language I can do things other than web development (for Ruby I know you can do more stuff but it might be just a waste of time to learn that other language. However, learning Python, Java, would open up app and phone development as well)

Don't mean to open a debate, please be concise (not like me) in your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From personal experience, there's several difference in both frameworks, particularly the way models are handled in cake vs yii.

In `cakephp` you cannot use `composite primary key`, this is the main `deal-breake`r for me. `Composite primary key` is supported in Yii.
`Cakephp` enforces convention, while `yii favors convention`, you are not forced to follow a certain standard.

Out of the box performance, I think `yii has the advantage`, but as with performance tuning, with proper cache configuration, and as long as you are careful in using the ActiveRecord patterns, they are not that much apart
As a side note, I have lead web app implementation with both CakePHP and Yii, the feedback that I got from the team was that the less experienced team preferes CakePHP, while Yii is preferred by the more experienced team. Make of that what you will.

Well it can turn out to be a very long debate. Each has its own life. So far from Experience I have found `Yii` to be most promissing than everyone. For me it matters who gives more work in less time. Cake is a bit heavy but Yii is light weight framework. I am from .Net Background but it took mew few weeks to get going with Yii

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Between Cake and Yii documentation, I think I would like Yii better for its approach to develop applications. I still have a little debate between Java Play 2 and Python Django, but among the PHP's Yii would be my choice.

Comment: thanks and you can always accept answer so that if anyone comes later knows what is answer. Regarding Play2 and django.....you just have to google between their features.

Comment: I'm just waiting to see if the first question gets answered:

Is there a module that would easily let you do this work in Java Play 2.0 Framework as in the mentioned PHP frameworks?

Comment: I put a single question in here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403042/is-there-a-code-generation-from-db-module-for-play-2-framework