# Is there a way to generate Code from a DB in Java Play 2 Framework?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

Does anyone know how to easily generate code from a database in Play Framework 2.0??

I know they have a module but it seems this is for version 1.X.

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRUD module is only for Play 1.2.x, it's not available in Play 2.0. It MAY be available in Play 2.1, but I'm not sure if that's still on the roadmap.

Comment: What would I be losing with 1.2.x if anything relevant? do you happen to know?

Comment: @mikiemorales 1.2 and 2.0 are very different, it's not a matter of losing some minor functionality, it's quite a jump.

Comment: Seems still no CRUD generator for Play 2.5.x. I think there should be a model/view/controller generator for Play 2.5.x.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has 2 aspects:

1. Create all models, base on a database. There you can start with the jpa-generator for play 1.x, because ebean use JPA too. It should be nearly what you need. Another approach is reverse engineering from ebean-models from database. But I fear this doesn't work. At [minuteproject](http://minuteproject.wikispaces.com/) I find no example. How ever Ebean and JPA-Model are very similar.
2. Creating GUI from DB-Model named scaffolding or crud. Some guys working on it and found some [bugs in play 2.0](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/376-cannot-route-to-inherited-methods-in-java-controllers). So I fear it will take some month till you get something like CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer Is no, this Is module Is not developed Yet In play! 2.0
But I'd snuggest working from java object to DB In play It is very easy. ebeans realy simplify the ORM work.
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaDatabase